# Control flow in asynchronous calls

Tags: c#, .net

I'm facing difficulties understanding how to handle program control during asynchronous flow.

I have a `SessionManager` class which calls the initiates the session and we need to register 
for the event `OnStartApplicationSessionResponse` and my control will return to the calling point. I will get the session id in the eventhandler after sometime or the error code if there is an error.

```
class SessionManager
{   
    public bool startUp(Object params)
    {
        try
        {
            serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider();
            serviceProvider.OnStartApplicationSessionResponse += new StartApplicationSessionResponseHandler(ServiceProvider_OnStartApplicationSessionResponse);
            serviceProvider.startUp(params);
        }
    }

    public void ServiceProvider_OnStartApplicationSessionResponse(object sender, ServiceProvider.StartApplicationSessionResponseArgs e)
    {
        //e.getError
        //I will get the session Id here or error code
    }
}
```

How do I get sessionId or the error as my control is now at the calling position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the C# feature async and await you are able to rewrite an asynchronous flow into something that is like a synchronous flow. You have only provided some fragments of your code so to provide a complete example I have created some code that resembles your code:

```
class StartEventArgs : EventArgs {

  public StartEventArgs(Int32 sessionId, Int32 errorCode) {
    SessionId = sessionId;
    ErrorCode = errorCode;
  }

  public Int32 SessionId { get; private set; }

  public Int32 ErrorCode { get; private set; }

}

delegate void StartEventHandler(Object sender, StartEventArgs e);

class ServiceProvider {

  public event StartEventHandler Start;

  public void Startup(Boolean succeed) {
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    if (succeed)
     OnStart(new StartEventArgs(321, 0));
   else
     OnStart(new StartEventArgs(0, 123));
  }

  protected void OnStart(StartEventArgs e) {
    var handler = Start;
    if (handler != null)
      handler(this, e);
  }

}
```

The `ServiceProvider.Startup` method will delay for a second before firing an event that either signals success or failure depending on the `succeed` parameter provided. The method is rather silly but hopefully is similar to the behavior of your `ServiceProvider.Startup` method.

You can convert the asynchronous startup into a task using a `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
Task<Int32> PerformStartup(ServiceProvider serviceProvider, Boolean succeed) {
  var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Int32>();
  serviceProvider.Start += (sender, e) => {
    if (e.ErrorCode > 0)
      throw new Exception(e.ErrorCode.ToString());
    taskCompletionSource.SetResult(e.SessionId);
  };
  serviceProvider.Startup(succeed);
  return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

Notice how an error signaled by the `Start` event is converted into an `Exception` (in production code you should use a custom exception type instead).

Using the async and await feature of C# you can now write code that looks very much like synchronous code even though it actually is asynchronous:

```
async void Startup(Boolean succeed) {
  var serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider();
  try {
    var sessionId = await PerformStartup(serviceProvider, succeed);
    Console.WriteLine(sessionId);
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
  }
}
```

If an error is reported by the `Start` event you can now deal with in the `catch` block. Also the session ID is simply a return value of the function. The "magic" is that using `await` on a `Task` will return the result of the task when it completes and if an exception is thrown in the task it can be caught on the thread awaiting the task.

Answer (score 2):

You could use TaskCompletionSource to make the Event awaitable.

```
class SessionManager
{
    private ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public int SessionId
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Task<bool> StartUp(Object param)
    {
        _serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider();
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        _serviceProvider.OnStartApplicationSessionResponse += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // do your stuff
            // e.g.
            SessionId = 0xB00B5;
            tcs.SetResult(true);
        };
        _serviceProvider.startUp(param);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

The call would look like:

```
private static async void SomeButtonClick()
{
    var mgr = new SessionManager();
    var success = await mgr.StartUp("string");

    if (success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mgr.SessionId);
        // update ui or whatever
    }
}
```

**note:** This Feature is available in .Net 4.5.